# SocketCAN how can I get result of the operation

Tags: linux, c, socket, canbus

Is it possible to get the status of the CAN operation?

Example operation:

```
write(socket, &frame, sizeof(frame));
```

Is it possible to check if the frame was ACK-ed or get any other CAN status information using SocketCAN?